# A and B run in the same direction around a circular track of perimeter $6$km, A at $5$ km/hr and B at $3$ km/hr. After how much time will they meet?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, circles

Is the formula used to solve this circular race track problem correct?

> A and B run in the same direction around a circular track, starting at the same time from the same point. The speed of A is $5$ km/hr and that of B is $3$ km/hr. If the track has a perimeter of $6$ km, after how much time will the two meet?

The answer is $\frac{Perimeter}{V_a-V_b} = \frac{6}{5-3}=3$ hours.

If the two runners were running in opposite directions, then the answer would have been $\frac{6}{5+3}=\frac{3}{4}$ hour. This is quite obvious from the idea of relative speed. But when they are running in the same direction, both of them together have covered more than 6 km (perimeter) by the time they meet for the first time. Then how is it possible that the formula for the time taken for the first meeting is  $\frac{Perimeter}{V_a-V_b}$?

Comment: The formula is just shifting the frame of reference. It is as if B is standing still and A is running $2$ km/h. (It's the same formula and explanation for your example where they run in opposite directions.)

Comment: I understand it now. If you see the situation as A and B being 6 km (perimeter) apart at the starting point and A chasing B, it becomes clear.